# How to avoid repeating try block

Tags: java

I'm coding a webservice in Java using aws and in many method i need to have a try catch block that can actually log any errors that can occur in the execution of each exposed methods.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "listingBucket")
public String listingBucket() {
    String message = "";        
    try {
        message = "Listing buckets";            
        for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
            message += " - " + bucket.getName();
        }
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        message += "Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.";
        message += "Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage();
        message += "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode();
        message += "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode();
        message += "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType();
        message += "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId();
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        message += "Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.";
        message += "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage();
    }
    return message;
}
@WebMethod(operationName = "addObjectToBucket")
public String addObjectToBucket(String bucketName, String objectName, File file) throws IOException{
    if ( file == null ){
        file = createSampleFile();
    }
    String message = "";        
    try {
        message += "Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n";     
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectName, file));
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        message += "Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.";
        message += "Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage();
        message += "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode();
        message += "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode();
        message += "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType();
        message += "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId();
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        message += "Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
                + "such as not being able to access the network.";
        message += "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage();
    }
    return message;        
}
```

How Can i avoid to repeat this try catch block throw all methods that use this kind of stuff ?

Thanks for your help !

Edit : Actually I modified the code :

```
private String parseError(AmazonServiceException ase) {
    String message;
    message = "Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
            + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.";
    message += "Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage();
    message += "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode();
    message += "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode();
    message += "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType();
    message += "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId();
    return message;
}

private String parseError(AmazonClientException ace) {
    String message;
    message += "Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
            + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
            + "such as not being able to access the network.";
    message += "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage();
    return message;
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "listingBucket")
public String listingBucket() {
    String message = "";
    try {
        message = "Listing buckets";
        for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) {
            message += " - " + bucket.getName();
        }
    } catch (AmazonServiceException exc) {
        message += parseError(exc);
    } catch (AmazonClientException exc) {
        message += parseError(exc);
    }
    return message;
}
```

Clearer indeed ! :)

I'll just take a look about the command pattern to see if I can use it for this kind of application.

Comment: You need Java 8 lambdas to do this cleanly. Is that an option?

Comment: Note: `message = ` *replaces* the previous value. You only need to do this once, and doing it more than once discards the previous value.

Comment: Actually yes i'm using Java 8 and i'm looking about Lambda, if you have a solution with that i'm curious to take a look on it ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects in here.

One thing is about the code repetition in the catch block; which can be easily turned into something like

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

public String buildMessageFor(AmazonServiceException ase) {
... }

public String buildMessageFor(AmazonClientException ase) {
... }
...
```

You can even unit test that thing very easily (where "naming" could be improved; but I guess the example should be good enough to get you going).

That would also make it easier in the future to turn from "pure string" messages into something else. You know, hardcoding user messages in source code is not the smartest thing to do.

The other part, the try/catch itself; somehow depends. You see, the try/catch is an essential part of your operations; so many people would argue that you simply keep that structure in your code. The only alternative would be to define some kind of interface like

```
public interface RunAmazonOperation {
public void run() throws Amazon...
}
```

Then you can write down all your operations as little classes implementing that interface; to be called by some framework that does the try/catch for you. If that is worth the price ... depends on your application.

In other words: if you turn to the "command" pattern; you might find it useful to define a variety of "commands"; implementing that interface; thus reducing the number of places with try/catch dramatically.

Comment: This is an improvement in repeating the *body* of the catch sections.

Comment: yeah I know that pure string message is not smart but, actually it's only for testing purpose. It's just for me being able to construcct a simple Webservice that use The amazon SDK.
I'll improve that part later because it's the back end webservice. There will be an AngularJS Webapp to consume that Webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with methods. One possibility would look like:

```
String parseError(AmazonServiceException ase){
    String message;
    message = "Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
            + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.";
    message += "Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage();
    message += "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode();
    message += "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode();
    message += "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType();
    message += "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId();
    return message;
}

String parseError(AmazonClientException ace){
    String message;
    message = "Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
            + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with S3, "
            + "such as not being able to access the network.";
    message += "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage();
    return message;
}
```

Now you can just write:

```
catch(AmazonServiceException exc){
    message=parseError(exc);
}
catch(AmazonClientException exc){
    message=parseError(exc);
}
```

Comment: And yes i forgot the + before the "=" x)) my bad on this one !

Comment: Well, this happens. The first time in a catch you would have seen it :-).